# Relative File Paths in Julia

Tags: julia

How can I read a file from a subfolder.

```
... folder ------ subfolder_1
             |
             |--- subfolder_2
```

1. How can I access a file **in** `subfolder_1` **from** `folder`?
2. How can I access a file **in** `subfolder_1` **from** `subfolder2`?

---

Reason I'm asking is that I wanted to read an Excel file (using the `XLSX` package) but it does not work. ("*MethodError: no method matching readtable(::String...*") I guess I'm doing something else wrong here.

Also, I feel like others might be interested in this question as well.

Answer (score 1):

MethodError means the function you are trying to use isn't designed for the inputs you fed in. To get more information about a function and the arguments it requires, you can type `? <functionname>` in the REPL after you have typed `using <packagename>`.

In this case `? readtable` shows the following:

`readtable(filepath, sheet, [columns]; [first_row], [column_labels], [header], [infer_eltypes], [stop_in_empty_row], [stop_in_row_function]) -> data, column_labels`

The first two arguments `filepath` and `sheet` are required. Arguments in brackets are optional. In your case, you need to add a second string argument which contains the sheet name you want to read from the XLSX file. The help also shows that the output will be a tuple containing `(data, column_labels)`, so be prepared to handle that. Often this tuple will be converted to a DataFrame using DataFrames.jl and the function `DataFrame()` like `DataFrame(readtable(filepath,sheet))`.

As for accessing folders and subfolders, the path you enter can be relative to Julia's current working directory or an absolute path which will depend on your operating system. Subfolders are indicated with a `/` like `"folder/subfolder"`. You can go up one folder with a double dot `..` like `"subfolder2/../subfolder1"`.